# Unable to change SWT widgets styling

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, desktop-application

I am making a demo standalone application where I have a list and a link SWT widget. I want the user to be able to change there properties`(SWT.BORDER,SWT.H_SCROLL,etc.)` by using check-boxes I provide.

```
Button styleBorderButton = new Button(stylesGroup, SWT.CHECK);
        styleBorderButton.setText("SWT.BORDER");
        styleBorderButton.setBackground(device
                .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        styleBorderButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                linkWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BORDER));
                linkWidget.redraw();
                linkWidget.update();
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I don't want to `dispose()` my widget to replace it as it would be heavy on the application every time user changes the style and the newly created widget wont have its scope out of the function to use it else where.

Can someone suggest me an alternative method to achieve this.

Comment: You haven't really told us what it is you want to change. Note that the style flags specified on the constructor (SWT.BORDER and the like) cannot be changed.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to be changed. Other parameters can be altered to by using `redraw()` but these style flags are the main issue. Do you have any alternative approach for achieving the task?

Comment: If it is a limited number of different things you want to show you can create them all at the start and change which ones are visible. Otherwise you will have to dispose and recreate.

Comment: Creating them in the beginning would take too much memory. Regarding the recreation of widget, its scope is limited to the `widgetSelected` function and I cannot use the recreated widget anywhere else.

Comment: Just assign the created widget to a field in your class to keep track of it. Unless you are creating thousands of controls I seriously doubt that memory will be a problem.

Comment: Once we declare it as a class variable, it needs to be `final` for using it in `widgetSelected` function. Being `final`, we cannot assign a new object to that reference. then how to achieve what you just suggested?

Comment: Not so, fields in the class don't need to be final. A local variable in the enclosing method has to final. You can also call a method in the class from widgetSelected.